# Work out item prices from total price.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So my maths teacher has just sprung this on us on our homework and has taught us basic algebra. However when it comes to worded maths questions I really struggle. I'm not going to write down the correct answer on my homework as I don't understand how to do it, but I really want to know how you would work it out.

2 Regular pizzas and 3 small pizzas cost £28

8 Regular pizzas and 9 Small pizzas cost £100

**Work out the price of..**

A regular pizza =

A small pizza =

Comment: Call $x$ the price of a regular pizza, $y$ the price of a small pizza, then use your data to obtain a system of two equations.

Comment: You could use logic. You know 2 regular and 3 small pizzas cost £28. So remove 2 regular pizzas, 3 small pizzas and £28 from your second condition. Repeat.

Comment: hint: triple all of the amounts in the first sentence, then read both (updated) sentences again

Answer (score 2):

Following Aretino's comment, you want to find the price for a regular pizza and the price for a small pizza. Since we don't know these, let's label them $x$ and $y$.

$x = $regular pizza price

$y =$small pizza price

From here, we make two equations with the information we are given. $2$ regular pizzas and $3$ small pizzas cost £$28$, so $2x + 3y = 28$. Also, $8$ regular pizzas and $9$ small pizzas cost £$100$, so $8x + 9y = 100.$

This gives us a system of equations. 
$$2x + 3y = 28\\ 
8x + 9y = 100$$

Solving this system of equations using any method you prefer will give you the price for each pizza.